# Veevalidate - Buefy - How can i use the error outside of ValidationProvider?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vee-validate, buefy, v-slot

I tried to use the ValidationProvider errors outside of the tag but it didn't work.
Here is my code :

```
<ValidationObserver
  ref="obs"
  v-slot="{ errors }"
>
  <b-field
    :type="{ 'is-danger': errors.phone[0] }"
    class="has-margin-bottom-0"
  >
    <div class="control">
      <b-select
        v-model="localPrefix"
        class="no-danger phone-prefix"
      >
        <option
          v-for="phonePrefix in phonePrefixTypes"
          :key="phonePrefix.id"
          :value="phonePrefix.id"
        >
          {{ phonePrefix.prefix }}
        </option>
      </b-select>
    </div>
    <ValidationProvider
      v-slot="{ errors }"
      :vid="name"
      :name="label"
      mode="lazy"
      slim
      :rules="maxLength.validation"
    >
      <b-input
        v-model="localPhone"
        :maxlength="maxLength.length"
        :class="{ 'is-danger': errors.phone[0] }"
        :has-counter="false"
        type="tel"
        expanded
      ></b-input>
    </ValidationProvider>
  </b-field>
  <b-field
    :type="{ 'is-danger': errors.phone[0] }"
    :message="errors.phone"
    class="is-margin-top-0em"
  ></b-field>
</ValidationObserver>
```

The problem is, with this code, `errors.phone` didn't existe at this time.
I supposed that i tried to used it before any validation of the provider, because if i use `errors` and not `errors.phone`, it's work but it return the object phone and not the error of the validation.

I think i need to initialize `errors.phone` but i don't know how to use the v-slot variable outside of the provider.

I hope you understand my problem, and thank you all for helping me !

Answer (score 0):

You're close to having this right I think.  Inside the ValidationProvider, you use `errors` directly.  Inside the ValidationObserver (but outside the VP) you use `errors[<vid>]`.  In your example it isn't clear that the `vid` of your VP is in fact "phone", but assuming it is, all you should need to do is change your VP code to look like this:

```
<ValidationProvider
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  :vid="name"
  :name="label"
  mode="lazy"
  slim
  :rules="maxLength.validation"
>
  <b-input
    v-model="localPhone"
    :maxlength="maxLength.length"
    :class="{ 'is-danger': errors }"
    :has-counter="false"
    type="tel"
    expanded
  ></b-input>
</ValidationProvider>
```

Comment: Well, yes the `vid` of my VP is "phone". I declare the variable in my props and is by default "phone".

I tried to only use `errors` and not `errors.phone` in my VP, and continue to use `errors.phone` outside. But i'm sad to tell you this didn't work... I have the same error : `TypeError: "errors.phone is undefined"`

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying now.  What if you use something like `errors.phone?errors.phone[0]:''` when you're outside of a ValidationProvider?

Comment: Either way, I think it's probably a bug, so I filed one with the library for you:  https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2546

Comment: Thank's guy for helping me. For the moment, `errors.phone?errors.phone[0]:''` look's like to remove the error's console. But i hope the github request will give us a better option.
I don't close this question, waiting github.